# How can I push a new viewController into an existing view within another view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, view, uiviewcontroller

Is it possible to push a new viewController into an existing view within another view controller?

Here is my setup to begin with:

[image]

You can see that I have a UITableView. When a cell is tapped, a new view controller is pushed using this code;

```
DetailTableViewController *viewcontroller = [[DetailTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
viewcontroller.item = (MWFeedItem *)[itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self presentViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
[viewcontroller release];
```

Unfortunately this looks like this though and sits on top of the bar at the top saying "Will Roberts"

[image]

Why is this happening as it's clearly outside of the view I set it to be pushed from...

Comment: Instead of "presentViewController", use "pushViewController"...

Comment: @objc, Have gone thru the answers.. How you are showing the table view initially?

Comment: I added the UITableView in Interface Builder and linked it up. It's being controlled from the AppDelegate.

Comment: hey you need some retina graphics :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Presenting new view controller with navigation controller will help you.

```
DetailTableViewController *viewcontroller = [[DetailTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
viewcontroller.item = (MWFeedItem *)[itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
[viewcontroller release];
```

//Edited

```
DetailTableViewController *viewcontroller = [[DetailTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

UINavigationController *nav1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController1];

[self presentModalViewController:nav1 animated:YES];
```

Comment: Doesn't work at all if I add "self.navigationController" rather than "self"

Comment: YourController *viewController1; 
viewController1 = [[YourController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav1=[[UINavigationController          alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
 [self presentModalViewController:viewController1 animated:YES]; //Try this snippet will surely help you.

Comment: There's no nib file, just .h and .m for DetailTableViewController

Comment: Okay I have edited the code in the edited section. Use this one may solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "presentViewController", use

```
DetailTableViewController *viewcontroller = [[DetailTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
viewcontroller.item = (MWFeedItem *)[itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];
[viewcontroller release];
```

or use modal view controller

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES]
```

Comment: Doesn't work at all if I add "self.navigationController" rather than "self"

Comment: I used the 'modal view controller' code, but the same thing happened as in the screenshot...